Triple Integrals for volume
I got stuck with this problem because I don't know how to find the values por $p$.
I also got $0$ to $\pi/2$ for $\theta$ and $0$ to $\pi/4$ for $\phi$
Let $S$ be the solid in the first octant inside the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 8$ above the cone $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$. Calculate its volume.

Notice how the sphere has radius $\sqrt 8$ so you'll have to integrate $r$ from $0$ to $\sqrt 8$. As for the angles, they're right. Also, I'd suggest you rather use symmetry: notice how the volume you are talking about is a a fourth of a spherical cone with zenithal angle $\pi/4$. Meaning,
$$V=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\sqrt 8}r^2\sin\theta\, \mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta\mathrm d\Phi=\frac{\pi}{2}\left[-\cos\theta\right|_0^{\pi/4}\left[\frac{r^3}{3}\right|_0^{\sqrt 8}=\frac{4(\sqrt 2-1)}{3}\pi$$

Thanks!
I got myself confused because I thought that z was between Z= 2 and the sphere
